# How to get the number of documents for each occurence in Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elastic index (say `file`) where I append a document every time the file is downloaded by a client.
Each document is quite basic, it contains a field `filename` and a date `when` to indicate the time of the download.

What I want to achieve is to get, for each file the number of times it has been downloaded in the last 3 months.

For the moment, the closest I get it with this query:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "when": {
                "gte": "now-3M"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "downloads": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "filename.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is something like that:

```json
{
    "took": 793,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "file",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "8DkTFHQB3kG435svAA3O",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "filename": "taz",
                    "id": 24009,
                    "when": "2020-08-21T08:11:54.943Z"
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "downloads": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 418486,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "file1",
                    "doc_count": 313873
                },
                {
                    "key": "file2",
                    "doc_count": 281504
                },
                ...,
                {
                    "key": "file10",
                    "doc_count": 10662
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So I am quite interested in the `aggregations.downloads.bucket`, but this is limited to 10 results.

What do I need to change in my query to have all the list (in my case, I will have ~15,000 different files)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `size` of the `terms` buckets defaults to 10. If you want to increase it, go with

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "when": {
                "gte": "now-3M"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "downloads": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "filename.keyword",
                "size": 15000          <-------
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there are [strategies to paginate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) those buckets using a composite aggregation.

Also note that as your index grows, you may hit the default *limit* as well. It's a dynamic cluster-wide setting so [it can be changed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html#search-aggregations-bucket).

Comment: Thanks @joe! I was indeed close :) I knew about that limit but I think I'm pretty far to reach it. I will also add a global `"size": 0` because I'm not interested in the `hits.hits` results.

Comment: Nice! Hey, since you discovered the global `size`, you may also be interested in response filtering -- i.e. skipping some potentially useless json wrappers: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering