# Paginate an aggregation sorted by hits on Elastic index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elastic index (say `file`) where I append a document every time the file is downloaded by a client. Each document is quite basic, it contains a field `filename` and a date when to indicate the time of the download.

What I want to achieve is to get, for each file the number of times it has been downloaded in the last 3 months. Thanks to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63939748/how-to-get-the-number-of-documents-for-each-occurence-in-elastic), I have a query that returns all the results:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "when": {
                "gte": "now-3M"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "downloads": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "filename.keyword",
                "size": 1000
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

Now, I want to have a **paginated** result. The term aggreation cannot be paginated, so I use a composite aggregation. Of course, if there is a better aggregation, it can be used here...

So for the moment, I have something like that:

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "when": {
                "gte": "now-3M"
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "downloads_agg": {
            "composite": {
                "size": 100,
                "sources": [
                    {
                        "downloads": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "filename.keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

This aggregation allows me to paginate (thanks to `after_key` value in response), but it is not sorted by the number of downloads - it is sorted by the filename.

How can I sort that composite aggregation on the number of documents for each filename in my index?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Composite aggregation don't allow sorting based on the value field.

**Excerpt from the discussion on [elastic forum](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/composite-aggregation-order-by/139563/5):**

> it's designed as a memory-friendly way to paginate over aggregations.
> Part of the tradeoff is that you lose things like ordering by doc
> count, since that isn't known until after all the docs have been
> collected.

---

I have no experience with [Transforms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transforms.html) (part of X-pack & Licensed) but you can try that out. Apart from this, I don't see a way to get the expected output.

Comment: Hello. Note that I use a composite aggregation, however I can change the aggregation used, if it helps me to achieve what I want.

Comment: Hello...I don't think there is a way to sort on value  & Paginate at the same time in elastic search. But I suggest exploring transforms as mentioned in the answer (licensed version).  It will be definitely costly (a new index will be created for the same) but it may solve your purpose.